# Reversing file name change made with find command?

Tags: linux, grep, find

Find is a great utility - and it's versatile. I trying to rename files by adding suffix or prefixes to existing file names. Cool.

`find  -name "*"  -exec mv {} {}.yo \;`

Now here's the though part I am not able to get - **if have to undo above operation, how do I do it?**

**Edit -**
I noticed that prefixing is not possible - is there a fix for this.

```
find  -type f -name "*"  -exec mv {} yu.{} \;
mv: cannot move './o.txt.yu.yu' to 'yu../o.txt.yu.yu': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -depth -name '*.yo' -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    mv -i -- "$file" "${file%.yo}" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

That's renaming all `file.yo` files (of any type including directory like in the command you used to add that `.yo` suffix) to `file` without `.yo`.  We're doing it depth first (leaves before the branch they're on) as otherwise if you rename `dir.yo` to `dir` first, when we get to rename `dir.yo/file.yo` to `dir.yo/file` that won't work as `dir.yo` no longer exists.

When using batch renaming, `-depth` is almost always better, so it's a good habit to always use it, the only thing to bear in mind is that it's incompatible with `-prune`.

Prefixing with `mv {} prefix{}` doesn't work because `{}` contains the full path including directory components, while you want to add the prefix to the file name, so you'd need something like:

```
find . -depth -type f -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*} name=${file##*/}
    mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/yu.$name" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

This time we use `-type f` to only rename *regular* files, to the exclusion of all other types of files including *directories*, *fifos*, *devices*, *symlinks*, etc.

Instead of doing this kind of thing by hand, I'd suggest using dedicated batch renaming tools like `mmv` or `zsh`'s `zmv`.

In `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(**/)(*).yo(#qD)' '$1$2'       # remove .yo suffix
zmv '(**/)(*)(#qD.)'   '${1}yu.$2'  # add yu. prefix to regular files
```

`(#q...)` is for *glob qualifiers* where `D` tells zmv to also consider hidden files or files in hidden directories like `find` does by default, and `.` is the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`.

Answer (score 2):

`yu../` No such file or directory.

try this

```
find * -type f -exec echo {} pref_{} \;
```

`*` asterisk expand into all files in current directory without dir,
if there are subdirectories use the option `-prune`, do not descend into it

there is also such a construction

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'echo  $0 ${0%%/*}/pref_${0##*/}' {} \;
```

but in it, positional variables begin their countdown from $0, that is, all files located in `{$0 $1 $2 ...} +` or `{$0} \;`

Accordingly, the number of files can be count as follows

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'echo  $#' 1 {} +
```

And you can display all files like this

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'echo  $@' 1 {} +
```

Here, instead of one, you can use any character or word without spaces. It will mean another additional file in the $0 variable

Comment: what is `bash -c` - does it mean bash command?

Comment: @samshers: yes, it does. nezabudka: +1,  nice `*` + `-prune` trick to list all files in current dir without full path.

Comment: @samshers, Call the child shell and pass the entire string to it. Try on the command line `bash -c 'echo $$'`

Comment: Note that `find *` will exclude hidden files in the current directory (and only in the current directory) and won't work properly if there are filenames starting with `-` (or named `!`, `(`, `)`...).

Comment: Leaving parameter expansions unquoted in POSIX shells such as bash has a very special meaning. You certainly don't want to do it here. See for instance [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) or [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: It's better to give a relevant name to your inline script to put in `$0`. So `-exec sh -c 'cmd "$1"' sh {} ';'` or `-exec sh -c 'for file do cmd "$file"; done' sh {} +` (here using `sh` as the *relevant name*, and also as the shell interpreter to use as there's nothing `bash`-specific in that shell code). See [How does this find command using "find ... -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +" work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324)

Answer (score 2):

to reverse:

```
find  -name "*"  -exec mv {} {}.yo \;
```

an simple way could be to :

First create a script "unyo.bash"

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for name in "$@"; do
  mv "$name"  "${name%.yo}"  
done
```

Then use it to unyo your files:

```
find  -name "*.yo"  -print0 | xargs -0 /path/to/unyo.bash
```

If you do not have "print0" and "xargs -0", you may need to do them one by one (innefficient as it spawns a bash each time):

```
find -name "*.yo" -exec /path/to/unyo.bash '{}' \;
```

Comment: great - what does `%` do in `"${name%.yo}" `

Comment: The standard equivalent of GNU's `-print0 | xargs -r0 cmd` is `-exec cmd {} +` which is about as efficient.

Comment: @shamhers: always look at the man page for `bash`, then ask. Around line 1250 in GNU bash 5.0.18  manual, you'll see that `"${name%.yo}"` removes the shortest possible matching pattern suffix and expands the result. Note that `%` specifies the shortest possible pattern suffix, but you'll also see `%%` which removes of the longest possible one.

Answer (score 0):

> Now here's the though part I am not able to get - if have to undo
> above operation, how do I do it?

You can use the below command.

```
for FILENAME in `find . -name "*.yo"`; do mv "$FILENAME" $(echo "$FILENAME" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//'); done
```

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Also, why use command substitution and `sed`, when a simple `"${FILENAME%.yo}"` will do?

Comment: -1 I'm afraid your answer doesn't add anything that wouldn't be already sufficiently covered by the other three answers here. Please edit your answer to clarify the advantages of your approach.